# How to get julia package UUID

Tags: julia

How to get the **UUID** of the third-party package without installing it on my computer?
Now I can only open the  `project.toml` file to view after installing the third-party package locally on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Pkg
Pkg.METADATA_compatible_uuid("JuliaAstro")
```

Credit goes to Stefan K.
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/a-quick-and-dirty-tool-for-generating-project-toml/11375/22

Comment: This seems to be outdated for newer versions

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind would be to just find the package on Github and look into its `Project.toml`.

However, if you have an updated `Pkg` system set up for the default package repository, there should also be a folder like `~/.julia/registries/General`, containing in the file `Registry.toml` a list of all packages of that repo sorted by UUID, and subdirectories for each letter from A to Z with folders for all packages, containing the metadata of every package.

(This is in my 1.0 installation -- it could have change a bit since then, but probably not much.  Have a look at [`Pkg`s documentation](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/) for details.)